# Evaluate integral using rectangular contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$\int_0^\infty {(\ln x)^2 \over {1+x^2}} dx$$

I need to evaluate the above integral using [this specific rectangular contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmL8Q.png) to obtain the answer $\dfrac{\pi^3}8$:

[image]

However the only example involving rectangular contours I've seen in the textbook or in the many Youtube videos I've searched is the following:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {{e^{ax} \over {1+e^x}}dx}$$

where $a$ is a constant between $0$ and $1$.

The hint is to use the substitution $x=e^t$ so I assume I'm suppose to turn the first integral into the form of the second, but then I end up with a $t^2$ I don't know what to do with. I am aware that if I solve the first integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ I just divide that answer by $2$ to get the answer from $0$ to $\infty$ so I guess the answer I'm really looking for is $\dfrac{\pi^3}4$.

Comment: I believe the exact same problem was answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191736/help-with-integrating-int-0-infty-frac-log-x2x2-1-operatorname?rq=1

Comment: As far as I can see, the answers do not solve the integral with a rectanglular contour.

Comment: @vitamind The accepted answer does it.

Comment: @user That's right, I must have overseen it. Voted to close.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, thanks. For some reason I couldn't find it while searching.