# Compute the integral $\int \frac{(\log x)^2}{1+x^2}\, \mathrm dx$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Compute the following integral from $0$ to $\infty$:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{(\log x)^2}{1+x^2}\, \mathrm dx.$$

Is my function here $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and there's a "hole" at $\log 0$ so we plug in $0$ into $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and plug into Cauchy's formula or?

Comment: You can't *directly* apply Cauchy's formula, since $(0,\infty)$ is not a *closed loop*. You have tagged this question with "contour integration", so you must surely know about needing a closed contour, and you must have seen examples... what contour do you think you should use to extract this integral? Furthermore, is there a mapping you can apply to this integral to change it into a nicer form?

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{(\log x)^2}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2}{2\cosh x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: @FShrike Yeah I couldn't have been able to make that connection to hyperbolic cos. How did you get to that

Comment: Use the substitution $u=\log x$. That detail is not important however, I just find integration easier with this substitution. The main thing is that you understand you need to find a contour that includes the integral you want - do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sort of stuck on that part @FShrike I know when I graph it, I get the positive $x$ and $y$ values so the curve goes around the positive ordered pairs ?

Comment: That's not very specific. When you graph what? I urge you; what is the contour you are using? A simple rectangle will do (for the $\cosh$ form of the integral)

Comment: In case you have not been provided with the answer, I will say that:  $$\int_0^\infty\frac{(\log x)^2}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^3}{8}$$For your reference

Comment: @FShrike would the contour then be an upper half circle for the first form of the integral, sorry I am weak at determining contours. I just can't see it for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134451/discussion-between-fshrike-and-hossien-sahebjame).

Comment: Also, the answers in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/191736/695196) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1030246/695196) question might be useful.